# Apache Ignite unknown node trying to connect

Tags: java, ignite, apacheignite

Unwanted node trying to connect Apache Ignite cluster. Due to which node goes down & cluster become unstable.
How to restrict unknown node trying to connect Ignite cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no filtering on Ignite side. The nodes are just listening for the traffic on specific ports.

In general, the task is more about your system administration and networking configuration. I.e. how to limit access for a particular set of hosts only, how to configure a firewall, etc.

From Ignite's perspective, there is one thing though - do not use [TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#multicast-ip-finder) which is the default one. Instead, specify your nodes' list explicitely using [a static IP finder](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#static-ip-finder).

To not mix the clusters, you can also configure non-standard communication [`47100`] and discovery [`47500`] ports and set them to, say, `42100` and `42500` respectively. More details i[n the documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration#discovery).